# minimal polynomial and relevance

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Suppose that we had $K[\alpha]$ and $K[\beta]$ as simple extensions over $K$. I have read that $[K(\alpha,\beta), K(\alpha)] \leq [K(\beta):K]$ and the reason for this was because the minimal polynomial divides something. I'm not sure what that something is and/or how the minimal polynomial is coming into play.

Comment: Something went wrong when you clipped parts of the formula out, so I put them back in. The first sentence is still unclear. I also removed the finite-fields tag, because it seems to me that the fields are not assumed to be finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $[K(\beta):K]$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial $f_\beta$ of $\beta$ over $K$ and $[K(\alpha,\beta):K(\alpha)]$ is the degree of the minimal polynomial $g_\beta$ of $\beta$ over $K(\alpha)$.

Since $f_\beta$ also belongs to $K(\alpha)[X]$ and $f_\beta(\beta)=0$, we have by definition that $g_\beta \mid f_\beta$. Thus $deg(g_\beta)<deg(f_\beta)$.

Comment: is that not true only if $\alpha, \beta$ are algebraic? I was not given this.

Comment: If $\beta$ is not algebraic over $K$, then $[K(\beta),K]=\infty$ so the inequality is trivially satisfied.

Comment: why is that exactly?

Comment: By definition, $\beta$ is algebraic over $K$ iff $[K(\beta),K]<\infty$.

Comment: alright gotcha, thanks